# QT Plain C++ App -> -1073741515

Tags: qt

I am using QT, version 5.9.1 for Windows. I installed it with the standard settings.

Then I created a "Plain C++ application" with the "Desktop Qt 5.9.1 MSVC2015 64bit" Kit (the only available one), which then creates a simple main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I then press Ctrl+R, a console window opens, but it only says, I should press Return to close the window, no Hello World.

In the output panel in QT I read:

```
Starting C:\Users\user\QTProjects\build-plainConsole-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\plainConsole.exe...
C:\Users\user\QTProjects\build-plainConsole-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\plainConsole.exe exited with code -1073741515
```

Which, as I already found out, implies, that some library is missing. Shouldn't QT have configured the necessary dependencies? What am I missing?